# Application.LoadComponent() exits application - WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, progress-bar, pivot, system-tray

I am working to create a video application and while working on Integration with music+video hub i came to a very strange problem. here is what i am doing

taping on music history item application launches MainPage.xaml, in OnNavigate() function i am checking if the history item was requested and if true then i use NavigateService.Navigate(videoPage.xaml). But this is exiting application no App Events raised just exits application without any app event.

As per my understanding there is no way to debug this scenario hence I simulated it somehow and noticed that NavigateService.Navigate is working fine but call of Application.LoadComponent() function is the one which is causing all this.

Strange things are

- The VideoPage.xaml opens perfectly on other event excepts this one
- It worked before and its just not working now.
- I found no way to check why it is exiting whithout raising any event.
- Its working on Simulator but not on Device.

I have tried clean solution. :(

please help me or atleast give me some workaround to get the error message.

**Update:**

I found solution to this seems like a workaround but its working anyway.
MainPage.xaml contains a pivot control and on event of pivot_selectionChanged it makes a httpwebrequest and also shows progressbaar on systemTray. (this event raises when first time page loads)

In OnNavigatedTo event i was checking if i need to navigate to other page or not and if yes then i was making  navigate call followed by a "return" statement.

yesterday it came to my knowledge that return doesn't stop control loading events and page was invoking pivot_selectionChanged anyway. so instead of attaching event of pivot_selectionChange in xaml I moved it in code file. that worked.

But the question still remains why the Application is exiting without raising any exception not even Application_Close event. And what was the real problem is it pending HttpWebRequest or Progressbar in systemTray which is causing such trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The app is probably raising an exception, just you cant see it because you no longer have the debugger attached. Suggest adding a message box to the unhandled exception event handler in your App.xaml.cs

```
 private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs 
 {
     MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString(), "Unhandled Exception ", MessageBoxButton.OK);
 }
```

Comment: i have tried this and also i have simulated this situation in debug mode as well.